# Saving a char value with fwrite returns incorrect data when loaded

Tags: c

I am using the frwite feature to save previous math equation result data and the code works when using integers but if I use char values (which I am trying to implement in order to make a certain future feature possible), I get weird values back. For example when the result `50` was saved, when the data was loaded I got the following:

```
2


2
```

The following is the code I wrote in question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cbm.h>

int integer1;
int integer2;
int integer3;
int option;
char save;
char c;
FILE *fp; //?????

void startup() {
    textcolor (COLOR_WHITE);
    bordercolor (COLOR_BLACK);
    bgcolor (COLOR_BLACK);
    clrscr ();
}

void get2nums() {
    printf("FIRST NUMBER?\n");
    scanf("%d", &integer1);
    printf("SECOND NUMBER?\n");
    scanf("%d", &integer2);
}

void addition() {
    get2nums();
    save = integer1 + integer2; //save into the save variable which will provide input to the save file function
    printf("%d", save);
    printf("\n");
}

void subtraction() {
    get2nums();
    save = integer1 - integer2; //save into the save variable which will provide input to the save file function
    printf("%d", save);
    printf("\n");
}

void multiplication() {
    get2nums();
    save = integer1 * integer2; //save into the save variable which will provide input to the save file function
    printf("%d", save);
    printf("\n");
}

void division() {
    get2nums();
    if(integer2 == 0)
        printf("Div by 0 undefined\n");
    else
        save = integer1 / integer2; //save into the save variable which will provide input to the save file function
        printf("%d with %d remainder", integer1 / integer2, integer1 % integer2);
        printf("\n");
}

static void savedata(void) {
    char data_out = save; //Data that goes into the file

    //Saving
    _filetype = 's'; //Does this set the file as a .SEQ?
    if ((fp = fopen ("CALCDATA", "w")) == 0) {
        printf("ERROR COULD NOT OPEN FILE\n\r"); //Error handler
        printf("CHECK DISK DRIVE\n"); 
        exit(1);
    }
    fwrite (&data_out, sizeof(data_out), 1, fp);
    fclose (fp);
}

static void loaddata(void) {
    _filetype = 's';
    if ((fp = fopen ("CALCDATA", "r")) == 0) {
        printf("ERROR COULD NOT OPEN FILE\n\r");
        printf("CHECK DISK DRIVE\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (1) {
        c = fgetc (fp);
        if (feof (fp)) {
            break;
        }
        printf("\n");
        printf ("%c\n", c);
    }
    fclose (fp);
}

void debug() {
    printf("%d", save);
}

int main() {
    startup();
    for( ;; ) { // uncomment this line and below for infinite looping
        printf("\n");
    printf("ADVANCED CALCULATOR VERSION 0.9\n");
    //printf("CODED BY REDACTED\n");
    //printf("BUILD DATE: 12/12/2022\n");
    //delay(5000);
    //clrscr ();
    printf("CALCULATOR OPTIONS ARE:\n");
    printf("1. ADDITION\n");
    printf("2. SUBTRACTION\n");
    printf("3. MULTIPLICATION\n");
    printf("4. DIVISION\n");
    printf("5. SAVE PREVIOUS\n");
    printf("6. LOAD SAVE\n");
    printf("7. QUIT\n");
//  printf("8. DEBUG\n");
//  printf("5. ADVANCED OPERATIONS\n"); // TODO
    printf("PLEASE SELECT YOUR OPTION.\n");

    scanf("%d", &option);

    if(option == 1)
        addition();

    else if(option == 2)
        subtraction();

    else if(option == 3)
        multiplication();

    else if(option == 4)
        division();

    else if(option == 5)
        savedata();

    else if(option == 6)
        loaddata();
    
    else if(option == 7)
        exit(1);

    //else if(option == 8)
        //debug();

    else
        printf("INVALID RESPONSE\n");
    }  // uncomment this line for infinite looping
    return 0;
}
```

I checked using the function I wrote called `debug` to see if the results of the previous math problem were being put in the variable correctly and they were. This leads me to the conclusion that it is something with the way the save or load code is written that is causing this issue. Also to note, I have previously gotten char data to save, but only when it was predefined with the `char data_out` variable written as `char data_out[]`. Any information on this issue helps, thanks!

Comment: Please remove those portions of this code not related to the specific question.

Comment: Have you tried running your code line-by-line in a debugger while monitoring the control flow and the values of all variables, in order to determine in which line your program stops behaving as intended? If you did not try this, then you may want to read this: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/12149471) You may also want to read this: [How to debug small programs?](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: The ASCII code for the digit `2` is 50.  You need to know how to interpret the data to interpret it correctly.

Comment: first take the first three comments to heart, and familiarize yourself with datatype and why you may need to explicitly typecast when assigning from one data type to another.  Search for good site that provide free C tutorial, W3School is a good start.

Comment: When you print your results after computing them (and before saving), you're using `%d`.  Why did you switch to `%c` after restoring?

Comment: Is there a reason you're limiting yourself to type `char` (and therefore a range of either 0..255 or -128..+127) for the results of your calculations?

Comment: I don't know what `_filetype` is, but in answer to a question in a comment, no, I would not imagine that you could use it to "set the file as a .SEQ".

Comment: Also a good idea to not use so many global variables

Comment: I am using char so potentially if I want to include the equation that led to the result in the data, I could. Is there a better data type I could use? (In response to Steve)